# Minimal boot grub settings to run inside qemu

Tags: terminal, grub2, virtual-machine, qemu

I am running terminal only (arch-linux) distro under Quemu on mine raspberry pi4 mostly as a shortcut to access some tools not available on aarch64 (tried to make mine own packages to port them, but don't have enough skill/time for that). The virtualization support on a pi4 procesor is negligible and as such many things like framebuffer in this case just waste cycles.
So question is what would the recommended minimal grub settings for inside qemu be, to get maximum power with not bothering about thrills or any xorg, just bash, network and mine beloved mc.
(Guest system in mine case is ARCHlinux x86_64)

Comment: Ading this to a comment as to prevent of topic answer. I have not been able to get many tools running on Box64 in either prepackaged, nor latest (self-compiled)  form. I am researching usermode, but I am spending too much time on something that is secondary to mine tartget taks...

Comment: `Ading this to a comment as to prevent of topic answer` ... you edit the question instead

Comment: GRUB has nothing to do with xorg, bash or network